# How to specify a value's type in Haskell's Prelude?

Tags: parsing, haskell, types

I know Haskell is able to deduce a value's type, but I wish to specify it, I tried:

```
Prelude> a=2 :: Float

<interactive>:8:2: parse error on input ‘=’
Prelude> Float a=2 :: Float

<interactive>:9:8: parse error on input ‘=’
Prelude> let a::Float = 2

<interactive>:10:8:
    Illegal type signature: ‘Float’
      Perhaps you intended to use ScopedTypeVariables
    In a pattern type-signature
Prelude> let a::Int = 2

<interactive>:11:8:
    Illegal type signature: ‘Int’
      Perhaps you intended to use ScopedTypeVariables
    In a pattern type-signature
```

None succeeded. How to achieve it?

BTW, seems in Haskell everything(almost) is a function and is immutable. So should I call "a":

```
1. An object? (FP is not OOP)
2. Or, a function?
3. Or, a variable?
4. Or, a value?
```

Not sure what term does Haskell prefer?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ghci` is an interactive console, so, you cannot just write `a = 2 :: Float`, you have to use `let` form:

```
Prelude> let a = 2 :: Float
Prelude> a
2.0
Prelude> :t a
a :: Float
```

> BTW, seems in Haskell everything(almost) is a function and is
>   immutable. So should I call "a":

`a` is a value of type `Float`

Answer (score 3):

```
Prelude> let a = 2 :: Int
Prelude> a
2
```

`a` is a value, it's not a function (but functions are values).